# Python coverage badges, how to get them?

Tags: python, django, code-coverage

I am using Python coverage to test my apps. Looking at other developers on GitHub I see they have a small badge which shows the percentage of coverage. Using coverage, how can I generate these badges?

The coverage badge is the one I'm looking at below.

[image: badges]

Update: There are packages that generate badges i.e. nose-htmloutput! Cool

Comment: Don't dare to click on them.

Comment: Those badges usually link to the specific service that provides them. Each badge is usually provided by a different service.

Comment: @Carsten I have seen different ones going to many different 3rd party services when clicked. But what I wanted to really know is if this was something actually generated by the package coverage i..e like coverage reports html which could be included.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to generate badges on your own, you could try to load the total coverage percentage and then create an image, someting like this:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
from coverage import coverage

cov = coverage()
cov.load()
total = cov.report()

# total = 79.0

im = Image.new("RGB", (120, 20))
fnt = ImageFont.load_default()
d = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

d.text((10, 5), "coverage:", fill=(255, 255, 255), font=fnt)
d.rectangle([(80, 0), (150, 20)], fill=(220, 0, 0))
d.text((90, 5), "{:.0f}%".format(total), fill=(0, 0, 0), font=fnt)
```

[image: simple coverage badge]

Comment: There's a much easier way than writing this program: use [shields.io](http://shields.io).

Comment: @NedBatchelder Yeah I've discovered that today as well. Still thinking about creating a module for making those badges.

Answer (score 13):

You can *click* on those badges and it'll generally take you to the service that provides them.

The coverage badge is provided by https://coveralls.io/:

> Coveralls is a web service to help you track your code coverage over time, and ensure that all your new code is fully covered.
>
> There is but one prerequisite:
>
> - **Your code must be hosted on GitHub**

Once you have signed up and included the required configuration and integrations or packages when developing, you are given a image URL to include in your project documentation; the `python-coveralls` project has:

```
.. image:: https://coveralls.io/repos/z4r/python-coveralls/badge.png?branch=master
    :target: https://coveralls.io/r/z4r/python-coveralls
```

in their README for example, which renders as:

[image: 1]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I was thinking this was something generated by the package coverage itself. Thanks

Comment: I have found packages that do this without a 3rd party i.e. nose-htmloutput

Comment: @OrbiterFleet: note that that doesn't host an image anywhere. If you are talking about the coverage image on their PyPI and GitHub pages, then that is still handled by coveralls.io.

Comment: @OrbiterFleet: `nose-htmloutput` doesn't itself do coverage reporting *at all*, all you get is unittest success / failure / error reporting.

Comment: Yep sorry just tested,

Answer (score 7):

Based on the answer by Carsten, there is now a MIT licensed tool on PyPI for generating SVG coverage badges:

https://github.com/dbrgn/coverage-badge
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/coverage-badge

Answer (score 5):

I have written a python badge generation package that produces badges very visually similar to the main badge services.  It is highly flexible, you can import and use in your python code, or run from the command line.  It is simple, and self-contained.

You can set the badge label and value, and you can set the color based on thresholds.  There are pre-built settings for pylint, coverage, and pipeline success, but you can create any badge you like.

Here is a link to the github project with more detailed documentation: https://github.com/jongracecox/anybadge

Install with `pip install anybadge`

Example python code:

```
import anybadge

# Define thresholds: <2=red, <4=orange <8=yellow <10=green
thresholds = {2: 'red',
              4: 'orange',
              6: 'yellow',
              10: 'green'}

badge = anybadge.Badge('pylint', 2.22, thresholds=thresholds)

badge.write_badge('pylint.svg')
```

Example command line use:

```
anybadge --label pylint --value 2.22 --file pylint.svg 2=red 4=orange 8=yellow 10=green
```

Answer (score 3):

To complete [Carsten's answer and the associated comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29296802/7262247), you can now use the `genbadge` commandline tool (installed with `pip install genbadge`) to generate a badge for a few tools including `pytest`, `coverage` and `flake8`. Options are provided to generate this badge using `shields.io` HTTP API or a local SVG template included in the package, resulting in badges such as:

[image]

The command

```
> genbadge coverage
```

Should suit your needs. See [`genbadge` documentation](https://smarie.github.io/python-genbadge/) for details, in particular to see how you can make those badges redirect the user to the test/coverage/flake8 report. (I'm the author by the way ;) )

Answer (score 2):

All of the answers above depend on some library or third-party providers (coveralls et al).

In my case, I needed to generate such a badge for code coverage. I wanted it to be simple and not load my docker image with unnecessary library and be less CPU intensive.
I realized having an `image/svg+xml` makes more sense than generating a png file in this case.

Here is a simple bash code script and below are the advantages I think over generating jpeg/png file

```
# generate coverage icon
COVERAGE_BADGE="${COVERAGE_DIR}/coverage.svg"

#Get this coverage from whatever tool you are using. In our case it was go tool cover
COVERAGE_TEXT="78.3%"
SVG_XML_DATA='<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="124" height="20">
<linearGradient id="b" x2="0" y2="100%">
<stop offset="0" stop-color="#bbb" stop-opacity=".1"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-opacity=".1"/>
</linearGradient>
<mask id="a">
<rect width="124" height="20" rx="3" fill="#fff"/>
</mask>
<g mask="url(#a)">
<path fill="#555" d="M0 0h52v20H0z"/>
<path fill="#97CA00" d="M52 0h72v20H52z"/>
<path fill="url(#b)" d="M0 0h124v20H0z"/>
</g>
<g fill="#fff" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Verdana,DejaVu Sans,Geneva,sans-serif" font-size="11">
<text x="26" y="15" fill="#010101" fill-opacity=".3">gocov</text>
<text x="26" y="14">gocov</text>
<text x="87" y="15" fill="#010101" fill-opacity=".3">PLACEHOLDER</text>
<text x="87" y="14">PLACEHOLDER</text>
</g>
</svg>'

SVG_XML_DATA_FILLED=$(sed "s/PLACEHOLDER/$COVERAGE_TEXT/g" <<<"$SVG_XML_DATA")
echo "$SVG_XML_DATA_FILLED" > $COVERAGE_BADGE

# upload bagde to s3
aws s3api put-object \
    --bucket dev.team \
    --content-type "image/svg+xml" \
    --key "coverage/${CODEBUILD_SOURCE_VERSION}.svg" \
    --body "${COVERAGE_BADGE}"
```

We used s3 to host svg but you technically host it on any http server

The advantages over png generation were pretty clear

1. No dependency on any library
2. Most browsers support rendering
   image/svg+xml
3. It's all text, no binary generation. This was critical
   in our case as code coverage ran on every commit and we wanted to
   reduce our AWS CPU time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Badge which is hosted at http://badge.kloud51.com

The source code is available at Github: https://github.com/SavandBros/badge you can look at the code and see how it's been generated if you'd like to learn about it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it for a special use case. Python package. Sphynx documentation. I wanted to click on the badge and go to a coverage html table. My Python package is called pycax.

This requires `pytest`, `coverage` and `coverage-badge` Python packages.

In my docs/Makefile

```
codecov:
    python3 -m pytest -rxs --cov=pycax --cov-report term-missing ../pycax
    @coverage html -d $(BUILDDIR)/html/_codecoverage
    @rm $(BUILDDIR)/html/_codecoverage/.gitignore
    @coverage-badge -o $(BUILDDIR)/html/coverage.svg
    @echo
    @echo "Code coverage finished. The HTML pages are in $(BUILDDIR)/html/_codecoverage."
```

To make my documentation I run (well, actually it happens in a GitHub Action)

```
cd docs
make html codecov
```

In my `index.rst` file I have

```
|coverage| 

<body>

.. |coverage| image:: https://<username>.github.io/pycax/coverage.svg
   :target: https://<username>.github.io/pycax/_codecoverage
```

Note, the docs are built in docs/_build/html and that it getting pushed to gh-pages branch on remote

Answer (score -2):

It cost me about one day to show this badge, finally I chose `Github Action`+`Codecov`, and the steps can not be too simple:

See https://github.com/codecov/codecov-action

Comment: Codecov is not smooth to setup and you should mention it codecov is for public repo and for private repo only 5 users allowed.

Comment: as well as being a github actions related answer, the op is asking an application level  solution